# How to find the most common day name in a month?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, calendar

Is there a way to print the day of the week which appears most frequent in the specified month and year as a string. Like `Monday` and `Tuesday` and if there are any multiple days, the first one should be displayed.

First I tried to check with the `datetime` output but unable to find the calendar module to get this as day output.

```
import calendar

def usingcalendar(datetuple):
    l = []
    dt=list(datetuple)
    obj = calendar.Calendar()
    for day in obj.itermonthdates(dt[0], dt[1]):
        l.append(day)
    rev = l[:-8:-1]
    rev.reverse()
    print(rev)
```

I was trying to use `calendar.itermonthdays` to get the required iterator to use that to display days like 'Monday', Tuesday'. But only came up to this

```
[datetime.date(2020, 2, 24), datetime.date(2020, 2, 25), datetime.date(2020, 2, 26), 
 datetime.date(2020, 2, 27), datetime.date(2020, 2, 28), datetime.date(2020, 2, 29), 
 datetime.date(2020, 3, 1)]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter` for this. You can call the calendar's `itermonthdates` for a given year and month, then create a `Counter` of the weekday names using the `'%A'` format specifier of `datetime`.

```
import calendar
from collections import Counter

cal = calendar.Calendar()
year = 2020
month = 1
count = Counter(d.strftime('%A') for d in cal.itermonthdates(year, month) if d.month==month)
```

Then for example

```
>>> count
Counter({'Wednesday': 5, 'Thursday': 5, 'Friday': 5, 'Saturday': 4, 'Sunday': 4, 'Monday': 4, 'Tuesday': 4})
>>> count.most_common(1)
[('Wednesday', 5)]
```

Comment: It should be ```if d.month == month```

Comment: @SMVaidhyanathan thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 1):

Noob coder:

I was trying to solve exactly the same problem. I came up with this solution and it works.

```
import calendar
import collections.defaultdict as dd

days_count = dd(int)

obj = calendar.Calendar()

days = [x for x in obj.itermonthdays2(year,month)]


for day in days:
    if day[0] != 0:  #these are empty days in a monthly calendar
        days_count[day[1]] += 1

max_day = max(days_count, key=days_count.get)
```

This will give an integer value ( 0=Monday, 1=Tuesday,...  6= Sunday).
You can use a function or dictionary to convert the integer into a string representation of weekday.

FYI: This solution gives the first occurring weekday in case there are more than one most occurring weekday

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work.
whichever day come on 29th is coming 5 times in a month and coming first.
In case of Leap year, all days come 4 times, so Monday being 1st day of week should come.

```py
import datetime

try:
    print(datetime.date(year, month,29).strftime('%A'))
except ValueError:
    print("Monday")
```

Comment: Please have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) help page about how to format code properly.

Answer (score 0):

You just need the day name for any valid dates from the 29th to the 31st of the month. If any of these these are not valid dates then stop trying any more.

```
import datetime

def get_most_common_days(year, month):
    days = []
    for daynum in range(29, 32):
        try:
            days.append(datetime.date(year, month, daynum).strftime('%A'))
        except ValueError:
            break
    return days

print(get_most_common_days(2020, 8))
```

This gives

```
['Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday']
```

the most common days in August 2020.  These occur 5 times.  The days that are not listed occur 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer and it seems to be working-

```
import calendar 
from collections import Counter


obj = calendar.Calendar()

my_list1 = []
for i in obj.itermonthdays2(year, month):
    if i[0] == 0:
        pass
    else:
        my_list1.append(str(i[1]))

int_values = []
for i in my_list1:
    int_values.append(int(i))

num = Counter(int_values)
num = num.most_common(1)[0][0]
if num == 0:
    print("Monday")
if num == 1:
    print("Tuesday")
if num == 2:
    print("Wednesday")
if num == 3:
    print("Thursday")
if num == 4:
    print("Friday")
if num == 5:
    print("Saturday")
if num == 6:
    print("Sunday")
```

The end part is a bit long but I couldnt find any way to get past it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys    
import calendar
import datetime
from collections import Counter

def usingcalendar(datetuple):
    # Write your code here
    year = datetuple[0]
    temp = list(datetuple)
    if (year%4==0):
        temp[1] = 2
        datetuple = tuple(temp)
    print(calendar.month(datetuple[0],datetuple[1]))

    obj = calendar.Calendar()
    l = []
    dt=list(datetuple)
    obj = calendar.Calendar()
    for day in obj.itermonthdates(dt[0], dt[1]):
        l.append(day)
    rev = l[:-8:-1]
    rev.reverse()
    print(rev)

    try:
        print(datetime.date(datetuple[0],datetuple[1],29).strftime('%A'))
    except ValueError:
        print("Monday")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    qw1 = []

    for _ in range(3):
        qw1_item = int(input().strip())
        qw1.append(qw1_item)
        
    tup=tuple(qw1)

    usingcalendar(tup)
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the weekday of the first day of the month. Obviously, the weekday on which the first day of the month falls will be the most frequent one.

If there are multiple days it doesn't matter as they will come only after this and we need to find only the first one.

```py
from datetime import datetime

month, year = 2, 2020 
first_date = datetime(month=2, year=2020, day=1)
first_most_frequent_weekday = first_date.strftime("%A")
print(first_most_frequent_weekday)  # Saturday
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you should consider using pandas in case of multiple recurring values

```
import pandas as pd 
List = [2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1] 
  
# Create a panda DataFrame using the list 
df=pd.DataFrame({'Number': List}) 
  
# Creating a new dataframe to store the values with appropriate column name 
# value_counts() returns the count based on the grouped column values  
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=df['Number'].value_counts(), columns=[['Number','Count']]) 
  
# The values in the List become the index of the new dataframe.Setting these index as a column 
df1['Count']=df1['Number'].index 
  
# Fetch the list of frequently repeated columns  
list(df1[df1['Number']==df1.Number.max()]['Count'])
```

**Output**

> > [2,1]

Make use of this example in your scenario!